# Splitting existing edge in postgis topology?

Tags: postgis, point, topology

I try to use *topology.ST_NewEdgessplit* to  split an existing edge along this edge. 
I use the following statement:

> select topology.ST_NewEdgessplit( 'mytopo' , 3 ,(Select ST_Line_Interpolate_Point((select geom from mytopo.edge_data where edge_id = 3), 0.5)));

My expectation is that the interpolated point must be on edge 3 but I get this error message.

> ERROR: SQL/MM Spatial exception - point not on edge
>   SQL state: XX000

Why might this go wrong?